# Main seems to skip over one of my methods

Tags: java, arrays, methods

Apologies for posting a bit of a foolish question, but I cant seem to understand why my method startEndCoords does not seem to run properly through my main method here:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class MazeSolver {

// The name of the file describing the maze
static String mazefile;

// set global variables
static int arrayHeight;
static int arrayWidth;
static int startRow;
static int startColumn;
static int endRow;
static int endColumn;
static int cellsize;
static int borderwidth;
static int sleeptime;
static char [][] maze;

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    if (handleArguments(args)) {
        maze = readMazeFile(args[0]);
        startEndCoords(maze);


        if (solveMaze(startRow, startColumn))
            System.out.println("Solved!");
        else
            System.out.println("Maze has no solution.");
    }
}

// get starting & ending points
static boolean startEndCoords(char[][] mazeAsArray){
    for (int r = 0; r < MazeSolver.arrayHeight; r++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < MazeSolver.arrayWidth; c++) {
            if (mazeAsArray[r][c] == 'S') {
                MazeSolver.startRow = r;
                System.out.println(startRow);
                MazeSolver.startColumn = c;
                System.out.println(startColumn);
            }

            if (mazeAsArray[r][c] == 'E') {
                MazeSolver.endRow = r;
                System.out.println(endRow);
                MazeSolver.endColumn = c;
                System.out.println(endColumn);
                return true;

            }

        }
    }
return false;
}
```

The print statements within the method will not execute, not sure what im missing.

Thanks for your help.

[full code](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/f670edae277e16331492)

Comment: Try moving the method above main?

Comment: @Phyreprooph get the same result

Comment: When you step through your code in your debugger, are any of the values in the matrix `E` or `S`?

Comment: If the printlns don't work then they aren't called. Add some debug prints like `MazeSolver.arrayHeight` before the loop or `r, c` inside the loop

Comment: @ Peter Lawrey yes a sample output as it is will include them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that your `readMazeFile` method is intended to set some of the global variables you declare, but it actually doesn't. It instead declares its own local variables that happen to have the same names, and sets those. This leaves `MazeSolver.arrayHeight` at its default value of 0, so of course the for loop instantly bails before even running once.

Remove the `int` from the lines in `readMazeFile` that set `arrayHeight` and `arrayWidth`. This will make it use and set the existing static variables instead of creating new local ones.